# How to completely remove Realm database from iOS?

Tags: swift, realm

Now I get the error `Property types for 'value' property do not match. Old type 'float', new type 'double'`. How can I clear the database or migrate it successfully?

Comment: Post some code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To completely delete the Realm file from disk and start from scratch, it's simply a matter of using `NSFileManager` to manually delete it.

For example, to delete the default Realm file:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```

If you want to preserve the Realm file, but completely empty it of objects, you can call `deleteAll()` to do so:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
  realm.deleteAll()
}
```

**Update:** I feel I neglected to mention this in my original answer. If you choose to delete the Realm file from disk, you must do so before you've opened it on any threads in your app. Once it's opened, Realm will internally cache a reference to it, which won't be released even if the file is deleted.

If you absolutely do need to open the Realm file to check its contents before deletion, you can enclose it in an `autoreleasepool` to do this.

Comment: Nice answer, Tim. Can we copy a few records from old db to new db (that we want users to use), before deleting it?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj Thanks! Hmm, yeah you can easily copy values between Realms, but in this case, that means you have to hang onto the old Realm for a bit longer in order to copy data to the new one. I'd probably recommend saving the new Realm to a different location, and once you've finished copying the data, delete the old Realm and replace it with the new one. Make sure to do all of this in a `@autoreleasepool` so all references to the old Realm are released before you go to delete it. :)

Comment: **Swift 3:** `try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)`

Comment: @TiM how to ensure that no realm live object is being used at the time of deletion, cause i have tried both of yours method and still i receive an error of 'realm object is deleted or invalidated'.

Comment: What if you want to remove the Realm dependency as well. So you don't have access to `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL`?

Comment: You'll have to remember where you saved the Realm files on-disk yourself and delete them manually then.

Answer (score 6):

This is how to do in swift 4.1:

```
FileManager.default.removeItem(at:Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4.2:

```
func remove(realmURL: URL) {
        let realmURLs = [
            realmURL,
            realmURL.appendingPathExtension("lock"),
            realmURL.appendingPathExtension("note"),
            realmURL.appendingPathExtension("management"),
            ]
        for URL in realmURLs {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL)
        }
let url = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
remove(realmURL: url)
```

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the other comments are right, you should really look at : https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations

It gives a super clear explanation of how to do migration, and it's really simple, and far better deleting everything if it can be helped.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.2
To remove database:

```
func remove(realmURL: URL) {
        let realmURLs = [
            realmURL,
            realmURL.appendingPathExtension("lock"),
            realmURL.appendingPathExtension("note"),
            realmURL.appendingPathExtension("management"),
            ]
        for URL in realmURLs {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL)
        }
let url = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
remove(realmURL: url)
```

To clear database:

```
try? realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
}
```

Comment: You missed one `}` right above `let url =...`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `NSFileManager` to remove the file, also remove the `.lock` file and `.management` folder as well. Otherwise, if you try to recreate the realm file with the same name, it will give an error saying it can't find it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
   let realm = try! Realm()
   realm.deleteAllObjects()
```

You could also try deleting the realm off the device by plugging it into the computer, going to Xcode and then Devices, and then finding the current realm there and deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

While using `FileManager` would be suffecient for non-synchronized, non-in-memory Realms, you can delete the `.realm`, `.note` and `.management` files for a given configuration with the [Realm.deleteFiles(for:)](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V11deleteFiles3forSbAC13ConfigurationV_tKFZ) class method, introduced in Realm v4.2.0.

```swift
autoreleasepool {
    // Before deleting the files, guarantee
    // that all realm objects are deallocated.
    //
    // Deleting a realm file or any of its auxiliary files
    // while one or more instances of the realm are open,
    // might corrupt the realm or disrupt sync.
}

let configuration: Realm.Configuration = .defaultConfiguration

do {
    // Returns `true` if the Realm file for the given
    // configuration exists on disk, `false` otherwise.
    if Realm.fileExists(for: configuration) {
        // Returns `true` if any files were deleted, `false` otherwise.
        _ = try Realm.deleteFiles(for: configuration)
    }
} catch {
    // Handle error
}
```

You may safely delete these files when all instances of a realm are closed. Before you delete a realm file, make sure that you back up any important objects as you will lose all unsynced data in the realm.

For guidance on deleting realm files, reference [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/sync-changes-between-devices/#std-label-ios-delete-a-client-realm-file).