# Deleting just local realm when synchronized with ROS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using a synchronized Realm and need a way to delete just the local data for security. I can't use realm.deleteAll() because that would wipe everything from the realm object server I am synced to as well and I only want the local data removed. I also tried deleting the realm file with NSFilemanager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL() but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396319/how-to-completely-remove-realm-database-from-ios/37408455#37408455) SO post this is ineffective as realm will still cache itself. I need some way to wipe all local data without touching anything on ROS and require it to resync with ROS before it can retrieve anything again.

Answer (score 1):

You can let the user logging out from the server by calling `SyncUser.logOut()`. Then the sync session waits for all local changes to be uploaded to the server, after that, the local Realm file will be deleted (Probably it happens next app launch).

> Any pending local changes will continue to be uploaded until the Realm Object Server has been fully synchronized. Then, all of their local synced Realms will be deleted from their device on next app launch.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#logging-out