# RealmSwift: Able to perform CRUD operations even if we delete .realm file from disk storage in a running app

Tags: ios, swift, realm

**RealmSwift:** Able to perform CRUD operations even if we delete .realm file from disk storage in a running app

**Expected Results:** If .realm file is deleted in a running app, .realm file should be created with 0 records in models

**Actual Results:** If .realm file is deleted in a running app, .realm file is not created and if we print model records, realm model is giving results and able to add more records in model.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Created "test.realm" file on disk storage using below line of code:
   `var config = Realm.Configuration()
   config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("test.realm")`
2. Open the realm database with realm config using below line of code:
   `realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)`
3. Created a dog model:
   `class Dog: Object {
   @objc dynamic var name = ""
   @objc dynamic var age = 0
   }`
4. On a button click, adding data to dog model.
   `let myDog = Dog()`
   `myDog.name = names.randomElement()! //names array`
   `myDog.age = Int.random(in: 1 ... 100)`
   `try! realm.write {`
   `realm.add(myDog)`
   `}`
5. Deleted .realm file using below line of code:
   `let file = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
   try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: file)`
6. Now performing the step 4 and printing records:
   `let results = realm.objects(Dog.self)`

Data is added successfully even .realm file is not present on disk.

7. Kill and relaunch the app. Now .realm file is created again with zero records.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37408455/4081597

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely remove Realm database from iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396319/how-to-completely-remove-realm-database-from-ios)

Comment: Voted to close since it was already answered but the answer, in a nutshell: *If you choose to delete the Realm file from disk, you must do so before you've opened it on any threads in your app. Once it's opened, Realm will internally cache a reference to it, which won't be released even if the file is deleted.*

Comment: @KentaroOkuda my question is why it is giving records from Realm if we have deleted .realm file.

Comment: @Rob my question is why it is giving records from Realm if we have deleted .realm file. What is the best practice to achieve the expected result? "Expectation: If .realm file is deleted in a running app, .realm file should be created with 0 records in models"

Comment: @Jay my question is why it is giving records from Realm if we have deleted .realm file. What is the best practice to achieve the expected result? "Expectation: If .realm file is deleted in a running app, .realm file should be created with 0 records in models"

Comment: I answered your question in my above comment and there are two links before that which also explain why that's happening and provide some advice on how to handle it.